# Why is "OR operation" or OR condition non-sargable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In literature, I have read that using OR condition or operator in a WHERE clause makes a statement `non-sargable`. I am not sure why or how this could be true. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wikipedia is a source...

Comment: Wikipedia is an open platform. Wikipedia has the potential to collect sources, but given it's so easy to change those sources, manipulate them or otherwise revert them makes it a fluid collection with no oversight. So I disagree.

Comment: There are also great admins and moderators that do a great job in managing sources. But we're going a bit off topic :D
Could you tell me what non-sargable means?

Comment: If wikipedia is not trustworthy, why do you consider so trustworthy?

Comment: after looking up what `non-sargable` means, ... if a sargable clause is a clause which could use an index, the opposite should be true.

Comment: thanks, I'm sure you could help me wiht my question when you don't even know what non-sargable means. ...

Comment: This isn't true. If you run a query and use an OR in the WHERE it still shows index(s) are used (if appropriate ones exist) in the execution plan (SQL Server). Can you cite the source?

Comment: Thanks  "Ghost" for the reply! I actually have a couple of sources: one is a book called SQL Query Performance Tuning, 4th by Grant Fritchey, and  Database Systems: A Practical Approach to Design, Implementation and Management, 5th. Thanks again, and do you know how to open up "Seek Predicates" window? I don't know how to open that. I know it exists though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was provided by the author of the authoritative optimization book [SQL Server Query Performance Tuning,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430267437) Grant Fritchey. So here it goes:

"OR statements are much more optimized now than they used to be. But if you think about it, if I have an index and I want to match values that are equal to A or Z, the engine has to do multiple comparisons, not simply one. The sargeable conditions all result in a straight forward point lookup, or range lookup. So = A will walk a tree and retrieve the one row, or the set of rows, from the index for that value. But if it’s A or R, it can’t retrieve a range, it has to do other types of work. Sometimes you’ll see these done as two seeks with a JOIN operation. And that’s great. But other times you’ll see additional filter operators or scans. So, it’s not sargeable." (again, credit goes to the author)

Comment: I'd suggest you stop thinking about it, and examine the execution plan. Does the definition of *nonsargable* include "the engine has to do multiple comparisons"?

Comment: I'm not planning to become an operator of SQL Server. I'd rather understand the fundamentals and concepts and be a designer as opposed to an operator/technologist.

Comment: Well, designers are expected to deliver designs that perform well. You can look at the execution plan and observe that a query using the `or` operator does, in fact, take advantage of an index. (That's not my opinion; that's a fact.) Does the definition of *nonsargable* include "the engine has to do multiple comparisons, even if those comparisons use an index"?

Comment: @LearnByReading - That quote has at least one glaring error -- It should say `UNION` where it says `JOIN`.