# Conditional Join in SQL Server Left and right part of equal to in Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to conditionally join 2 tables in SQL Server. Here is the basic table structure and what I am trying to do:

```
Table A

A1 int 
A2 varchar
A3 varchar
A4 varchar

Table B

B1 varchar
B2 varchar
B3 varchar
B4 varchar

Select 1
    From A
Left Join B 
    ON Case When A.A1 Is Not NULL Then A.A1 = B.B1
            When A.A4 Is Not Null Then A.A4 = B.B4
            When A.A3 Is Not Null Then A.A3 = B.B3 and A.A4 IS NULL
            When A.A2 Is Not Null Then A.A2 = B.B2 and A.A3 IS NULL AND A.A4 IS NULL
```

But it is syntactically incorrect to give joins like this in ON. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `CASE` in SQL server is a `CASE` expression, it returns a **scalar** value. It's not a `Case` statement; that returns a boolean result.

Comment: @Mrug . . . Your query makes no sense at all.  If `A` has any rows, it is going to return `1` at least for each row in `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *appears* to be what you're after:

```
SELECT 1
FROM A
     LEFT JOIN B ON (A.A1 = B.B1) -- No need to check that A.A1 IS NOT NULL here, as NULL = NULL returns NULL
                 OR (A.A4 = B.B4 AND A.A1 IS NULL)
                 OR (A.A3 = B.B3 AND A.A1 IS NULL AND A.A4 IS NULL)
                 OR (A.A2 = B.B2 AND A.A1 IS NULL AND A.A4 IS NULL AND A.A3 IS NULL);
```

Comment: Nice!! I like this solution but forpas is super innovative.

Comment: Only problem with that one is that it's not SARGable, @Mrug . Not sure this'll be specifically performant either though :/

Comment: Larnu I also think forpas has not taken into consideration my conditions

Comment: Why it is not sargable?

Comment: Due to both the `CASE` and `COALESCE` @Mrug . The application of the functions mean that any indexes won't be able to be used.

Comment: @Larnu About the OR operator there is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099633/10498828 and other papers that explain why they do not improve performance even if they are *SARGable*.

Comment: I didn't say that mine would be performant @forpas, in fact, I specifically stated *"Not sure this'll be specifically performant either though :/"* I do, however, prefer to at least give the data engine a chance :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the columns of the table `A` to get the 1st non `null` value and the `case` statement for the columns of the table `B`:

```
ON coalesce(A.A1, A.A4, A.A3, A.A2) = 
  case 
    When A.A1 Is Not NULL Then B.B1
    When A.A4 Is Not Null Then B.B4
    When A.A3 Is Not Null Then B.B3
    When A.A2 Is Not Null Then B.B2
  end
```

Comment: This is super innovative answer! but my conditions are missing and A.A4 IS NULL plus and A.A3 IS NULL AND A.A4 IS NULL

Comment: They are not missing. Each when statement will be executes only if the previous ones are false. So when A.A3 is not null will be executed only if the previous are null.

Comment: ahh I see. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this following way-

```
SELECT 1
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
ON 
CASE
    WHEN A.A1 IS NOT NULL
        AND A.A1 = B.B1
            THEN 1
    WHEN A.A4 IS NOT NULL
        AND A.A4 = B.B4
            THEN 1
    WHEN A.A3 IS NOT NULL
        AND A.A3 = B.B3
        AND A.A4 IS NULL
            THEN 1
    WHEN A.A2 IS NOT NULL
        AND A.A2 = B.B2
        AND A.A3 IS NULL
        AND A.A4 IS NULL
            THEN 1
END = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

CASE statements are perfectly fine when using joins, however your statement is formatted incorrectly as it appears you are trying to return a condition within the CASE statement.  CASE statements when evaluated return a value, not an expression, so to use it properly it should be something like:

```
SELECT 1
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON
    CASE WHEN A.A1 IS NOT NULL THEN A.A1
    CASE WHEN A.A2 IS NOT NULL THEN A.A2
    ...
    END
  =
    CASE WHEN A.A1 IS NOT NULL THEN B.B1
    CASE WHEN A.A2 IS NOT NULL THEN B.B2
    ...
    END
```

However, this is a bit awkward, so I would prefer to rewrite it without a case statement like below:

```
SELECT 1
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON
    (A.A1 IS NOT NULL AND A.A1 = B.B1)
  OR (A.A4 IS NOT NULL AND B.B4 = B.B4)
  OR (A.A3 IS NOT NULL AND A.A3 = B.B3 AND A.A4 IS NULL)
  OR (A.A2 IS NOT NULL AND A.A2 = B.B2 AND A.A3 IS NULL AND A.A4 IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real query and care about performance, then multiple `left join`s with `coalesce()` is probably the best approach:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.col, b4.col, b3.col, b2.col) as col
from A left join
     B b1
     ON a.a1 = b1.b1 left join  -- don't worry, NULLs don't match
     B b4
     ON a.a4 = b4.b4 and
        b1.b1 is null left join -- no match previously
     B b3
     ON a.a3 = b3.b3 and
        b3.b4 is null left join -- no match previously
     B b2
     ON a.a2 = b2.b2;
```

Constructs such as `CASE` and `OR` tend to kill performance.